# Picking points in a plane under a curve given by a list

Tags: geometry, expression-test

Suppose that I have a set of points in a plane, which range from $x\in [0,20]$ and $y\in[0,10]$, and a curve given by a list of points in the same region:

```
data = Table[{RandomReal[20], RandomReal[10]}, {200}];
list = Table[{i, RandomReal[{5, 6}]}, {i, 0, 20}];
```

Now I want to select those points in `data` which are under the curve defined by `list`(where, for instance, such a curve is given by "step functions"). **What is the fastest way of doing it?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the `data` and `list` as defined:

```
if = Interpolation[list, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
regm[{x_, y_}] := 0 <= x <= 20 && 0 <= y <= if[x]
Show[ListPlot[list, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 10}], 
 ListPlot[GatherBy[data, regm], 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, {Red, PointSize[0.02]}}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Above", "Below"}], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Here are 4 ways to get the points:

```
a1 = Cases[data, x_?(regm@# == True &)];
a2 = Select[data, regm@# == True &];
a3 = Pick[data, regm /@ data];
a4 = True /. GroupBy[data, regm];
```

Answer (score 8):

This is likely equivalent to ubpdqn's answer internally, but I wanted to show off an answer with a "geometric" flavor:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "Legacy"]; (* for reproducibility *)
            data = Transpose[{RandomReal[20, 200], RandomReal[10, 200]}]; 
            list = MapIndexed[Append[#2 - 1, #1] &, RandomReal[{5, 6}, 21]]];

With[{xa = list[[All, 1]]}, (* cache abscissas *)
    underQ[pt_] := With[{k = GeometricFunctions`BinarySearch[xa, pt[[1]]]}, 
                        TrueQ[Det[PadRight[Append[list[[k + {0, 1}]], pt],
                                           {3, 3}, 1]] < 0]]]

ListLinePlot[list,
             Epilog -> Transpose[{{Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[4]],
                                   Directive[Black, AbsolutePointSize[2]]},
                                  Point /@ GatherBy[data, underQ]}],
             Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 10}]
```

[image: points above, points below]

Comment: thank you...learned a lot from this +1 :)

Comment: ConvexHull (with appropriate points on the boundary of $[0,20] \times [0,10]$) would be another geometrical way to go...

Comment: Instead of using the signed area (that is, `Det[PadRight[triangle, {3, 3}, 1]]`) like I did here, one could use the signed distance from a point to a line; for some reason, that method was slower, so I settled on using signed area.

Answer (score 6):

Your curve, plus two points makes a region.

```
Select[data, Element[#, Polygon[Join[list, {{20, 0}, {0, 0}}]]] &]
```

or

```
GatherBy[data, Element[#, reg] &]
```

where `reg = Polygon[Join[list, {{20, 0}, {0, 0}}]]` last two points defined by the range of $x$ and $y$.

Visual

```
Block[{reg = Polygon[Join[list, {{20, 0}, {0, 0}}]]},
 Show[
  ListPlot[
   {
    Select[data, ! Element[#, reg] &]
    , Select[data, Element[#, reg] &]
    }
   , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
   , PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}
   , PlotLegends -> {"Above", "Below"}
   ]
  , RegionPlot@reg
  ]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Or

```
Block[
 {
  reg = Polygon@Join[list, {{20, 0}, {0, 0}}],
  },
 Show[
  ListPlot[
   GatherBy[data, Element[#, reg] &]
   , PlotTheme -> "Detailed"
   , PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}
   , PlotLegends -> {"Above", "Below"}
   ]
  , RegionPlot@reg]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

```
Pick[data, UnitStep[data[[All, 2]] - Part[list[[All, 2]], Ceiling[data[[All, 1]]]]], 0]
```

Example:

```
data = Table[{RandomReal[20], RandomReal[10]}, {200}];
list = Table[{i, RandomReal[{5, 6}]}, {i, 0, 20}];

Show[{ListStepPlot[list, Right, Mesh -> Full],
  ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black], 
  ListPlot[
   Pick[data, UnitStep[data[[All, 2]] - Part[list[[All, 2]], Ceiling[data[[All, 1]]]]], 0], 
 PlotStyle -> Red]}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Example]

Comment: neat and thank you for introducing me to `ListStepPlot`,+1 :)