# Selecting points on either side of a curve

Tags: list-manipulation, data

I have the following array of data. Suppose I want only to keep data within the two lines. I can achieve my result using the following code:

```
data = Table[{i, RandomReal[{-10, 10}]}, {i, 0, 100}];
line1[x_] := 0.1 x - 10;
line2[x_] := -0.1 x + 10;
```

[image]

```
rf = RegionMember[Polygon[{{0, line1[0]}, {0, line2[0]}, {100,line1[100]}}]];
bool1 = rf[data];
notbool1 = Not[#] & /@ bool1
datain = Pick[data, bool1];
dataout = Pick[data, notbool1];
```

This has the desired effect.

[image]

Now suppose I only have one line, since I can't make a closed region what would be the best way to select points either above or below a line? What if the curve is not a straight line? Any ideas?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97299/picking-points-in-a-plane-under-a-curve-given-by-a-list

Comment: `Pick[data, RegionMember[HalfPlane[{line1[0], line1[1]}, {0, -1}], data]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some knowledge about (planar) analytic geometry facilitates this problem. Suppose now you only have `line1`, this

```
Select[data, line1[ #[[1]] ] < #[[2]] &]
```

selects out the points above `line1`; the key lies in the inequality. If it is connected by `>`, then the points below `line1` you will get.

Answer (score 4):

```
{in, out} = GeneralUtilities`SelectDiscard[data, line1[#[[1]]]<=#[[2]]<=line2[#[[1]]]&];

Show[ListPlot[{in, out}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Red}], 
 Plot[{line1@x, line2@x}, {x, 0, 100}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Opacity[.5, LightBlue], None}}}]]
```

[image]

```
{above1, below1} = GeneralUtilities`SelectDiscard[data, line1[#[[1]]] <= #[[2]] &];
{above2, below2} = GeneralUtilities`SelectDiscard[data, line2[#[[1]]] <= #[[2]] &]; 

{plt1, plt2} = Show[ListPlot[#, PlotStyle -> {Green, Red}], 
      Plot[{line1@x, line2@x}, {x, 0, 100}, 
        Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Opacity[.5, LightBlue], None}}}]] & /@ 
  {{above1,below1}, {above2, below2} };
Row[{plt1, plt2}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]