# How to count points under the curve?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I need a formula to calculate how many points are there under the curve $y=x$.[image: figure]

Comment: Some related: [(97299)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97299), [(157149)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/157149), [(181620)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/181620)...I think there's more, but couldn't find the right search terms.

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
p = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {50, 2}]
pu=Select[p, #[[2]] < #[[1]] &] 
Length[pu] (* number of points yi<xi*)

Show[{Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], ListPlot[p],ListPlot[pu, PlotStyle -> Red]}]
```

[image]

Comment: One could also use `pu = Select[p, Apply[Greater]]` in this case. A slower, but generalizable approach would be `rmf = RegionMember[ImplicitRegion[y <= x, {x, y}]]; pu = Select[p, rmf]`

Comment: How about if i want to do that in sine curve?

Comment: @Math Something like `Select[p, #[[2]] <Sin[ #[[1]] ] &] `

Answer (score 9):

```
p = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {50, 2}]
Count[p, {x_, y_} /; y < x]
```

This is many times more efficient for long lists:

```
Total[UnitStep[Subtract @@ Transpose[p]]]
```

## Edit:

A few timings under version 12.0 on macos:

```
p = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {1000000, 2}];
Length[Select[p, #[[2]] < #[[1]] &]] // RepeatedTiming
Count[p, {x_, y_} /; y < x] // RepeatedTiming
Total[UnitStep[Subtract @@ Transpose[p]]] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {1.31, 499894}
>
> {0.757, 499894}
>
> {0.0089, 499894}

Comment: Very interesting alternatives. By the way the last one is the slowest (MMA v.11.0.1)

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Really? That is indeed surprising... Unfornately, I cannot test it under v. 11.0.1; I have removed it recently.

Comment: Similar timings under v10.4 and 11.3.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann That is surprising. What if you try the compiled version `Compile[{{p,_Real,2}},Total[UnitStep[p.{1,-1}]]]`?

Comment: @Silvia Great idea to use `Dot`! And I am also surprised that `Compile` makes a difference here.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks! I realized only after posting the comment it's the `Dot` that actually makes the major difference :)

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`RegionMember`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember) for this:

```
reg = RegionMember[ImplicitRegion[y<x, {x,y}]];

Tally @ reg[p]
```

> {{False, 23}, {True, 27}}

This will not be as fast as Henrik's answer.